# Administering database variables in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-connection

I'm currently implementing multi-tenanted logic in an app, and while that's simple enough I've now become stumped on long term storage for all the variables. The variables are derived from a Heroku `database_url`.

```
def env_variables
  {
    host: ENV.fetch("#{@company_id}_DB_HOST"),
    port: ENV["#{@company_id}_DB_PORT"],
    username: ENV.fetch("#{@company_id}_DB_USERNAME"),
    password: ENV.fetch("#{@company_id}_DB_PASSWORD"),
    database: ENV.fetch("#{@company_id}_DB_DATABASE"),
  }
end
```

It's fairly simple to fetch the relevant variables from ENV, but administering 40-50 env-variables may prove painful.

The options as I see them

1. Set ENV-variables in an ansible-script. This we already do for some things.
2. Store database variables in files in the project. Probably easier to manage, but have to be deployed before taking effect.

Am I missing some awesome solution? How do people usually go about storing bigger amounts of database variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ENV**

Whilst I'm sure you can store the data in a file, I'd personally look at keeping them in ENV vars (probably with [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro))

Reason being that ENV variables are stored deeper in the stack (in the OS), and consequently aren't actually held by Rails itself. If the company ID's aren't going to change (they aren't dynamic), I'd just put them into a Figaro `application.yml` file:

```
#config/application.yml
156_DB_DATABASE: "db"
etc
```

Comment: For brevity I ended up using the Heroku-url for the database config and building a method for parsing it, but storing the url along with the rest of our ENV-config.